# How to return all values of all columns and the highest value of column_name in one select

Tags: php, mysqli

To return all the values of all columns and the value of the highest value of a particular column I get that way (two selects)

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT max(colun3) AS max_c FROM table");
$rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$maximo =  $rows["max_c"];

$result2 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM table");

while($rows2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {

    if($rows2['column3']==$maximo){
        $color = 'bgcolor=blue';
    }else{
        $color = '';
    }

    $var1 = $rows2['column1'];
    $var2 = $rows2['column2'];
    $var3 = $rows2['column3'];
    ...........
```

With the code above I can print on the screen what I want, but would there be a way to bring this result with just a select? something like

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT *, max(colun3) AS max_c FROM table");

while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

   ?????????
```

And if possible how could I print on the screen the results

Answer (score 0):

```
 $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT *,(SELECT max(colun3) AS max_c FROM table) FROM table");
```

that should add the max_c on every row of your other query.

Also it's recommended to not use * but instead write each column.

To print the result you can for example do this:

```
$assoc_array_of_results = mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
print_r($assoc_array_of_results);
```

Comment: d'ont work for my - `Call to undefined function mysqli_fetch_all() in` line `$assoc_array_of_results = mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);`

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo that part really isn’t the important one here; you can keep using `mysqli_fetch_array` to fetch the resulting rows individually.

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Like misorude said, use the mysqli_fetch_array instead if mysqli_fetch_all isn't working for you. The reason why it's not working is probably in your server settings, it requires MySQL Native Driver you can read about it here. http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php

Comment: Dear yasoh, I need to do a conditional within the while. See the edited question

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo To do a conditional within the while?, i can't figure out what is it that you need from your post edits.

Comment: I was wondering if it is possible to produce the same result with just a select in the same way as it was produced with two selects

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Isn't that exactly what i've answered to you on this question? use a nested query like in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use nested request as it was said

```
SELECT *, (SELECT max(colun3) AS max_c FROM table) FROM table;
```

you can also use a GROUP BY x WITH ROLLUP

```
SELECT *, MAX(colun3) FROM table GROUP BY YOUR_PRIMARY_KEY WITH ROLLUP
```

it should produce on the last line of your result a line with everything at null except the max column, with the right maximum value